# RSA high bits padding atack

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Can we use Coppersmith's attack if we know a few ciphertexts of the same plaintext, but there is a short random bit padding in front of message? Formula:
$$(2^k \cdot r + m)^3 \bmod n = c$$

Comment: Does $m<2^k$ hold?

Comment: Yes; the attack is similar in every aspect to [Coppersmith's variant](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.298.4806&rep=rep1&type=pdf) with $r$ on the least-significant part of the message, but with the polynomial $(m + r)^3 - c_2$ replaced by $(m + 2^k\cdot r)^3 - c_2$. In either case, $r$ needs to be smaller than $n^{1/9}$.

Comment: How can i change polynomial into monic in modular equation?

Comment: A root of $c_n x^n + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + c_0$ must also be a root of $x^n + c_{n-1}/c_n x^{n-1}  \dots + c_0/c_n$. So all you need to do is divide the polynomial by the leading coefficient.